# Google Maps: Get KML Layer URL from div.innerHTML

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

I'm following [this example](http://code.google.com/intl/pt-BR/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml-features.html) to make a sidebar with the information when user clicks from the pinned points in the map.

The thing I'm stuck here is this: from their source-code (Use Chrome? [See source here](http://code.google.com/intl/pt-BR/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml-features.html)) there is a hardcoded link and I'm wanting to get that link from a div.innerHTML.

So, from this code I changed:

```
var nyLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(
'http://www.searcharoo.net/SearchKml/newyork.kml',
{  suppressInfoWindows: true,
map: map});
```

to this:

```
var otherMap = document.getElementById('kml_link').innerHTML;
var nyLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(
otherMap,
{  suppressInfoWindows: true,
map: map});
```

But it never works. Already tried .toString() on the var, but nothing happens.

```
alert(otherMap);
```

...does show the link properly. Could anyone help me out? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You could make the following checks:

1. Double check that the value is really a proper string using a debugger (e.g. Firebug). Try `otherMap = otherMap.toString()` or `otherMap = "" + otherMap`.
2. Ensure that `otherMap` is a valid URL. Enter it (without enclosing quotes) into the address field of a browser.
3. Check that the content of your `otherMap` URL is a valid KML file. This could be the most likely problem. You can copy the content of the file http://www.searcharoo.net/SearchKml/newyork.kml into your `otherMap` file and try with it.

Comment: Thanks Jiri, but I already checked everything. It's really strange that it's happening. I'm getting the url from a wordpress custom field... maybe that's it? But what about .toString() not transforming it? It's really weird =/ But will check again anyways.